# Fourier transform with an exponential and Heaviside function

Tags: fourier-transform

I have to find the convolution product $e^t h(t) * h(t-1)$ using the property $\Phi(f * g) = \Phi(f)_{(w)} \Phi(g)_{(w)}$ where $\Phi$ is used to denote Fourier's transform and $h(t)$ is Heaviside function.

I started by transforming both sides to use the mentioned property, so I tried to transform $\Phi(e^{t}h(t))$ but I couldn't go further beacuse the integral seems to have no solution.

Is possible that the excercise has a typo or the transform is resolvable? I also would like to mention that WolframAlpha (software that I use only to check my answer) displays that it has no solution.

Comment: Uh this is not great for Fourier analysis. Are you sure that it is $h(t)$ and not $h(-t)$ or else not $e^{-t}$..?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure :/ I'm beggining to assume that prof has a typo

Comment: You're right, I've deleted that tag, sorry for that

Comment: If there is no typo then it is easy: the Fourier transform integral renders a divergent improper integral, so there's no solution.